# is it haram to get really excited by thinking about having sex?

Tags: sex, halal-haram

I am an unmarried muslim girl. I can not stop myself thinking about having sex and that is why my whole body (especially my private part) gets so excited and I start to sweating. I do not do masturbate and do not watch porn. Is it haram to get crazy by thinking about sex?

Please give me some suggestion, how can I stop it?

Comment: What's the reason why it should be haram? Please explain! Note that this site is not a peer support so the alst part of your question is somewhat off-topic as it migth be regarded as an advice-request.

Comment: I was curious to know that if this act is haram or not. As I do not know so I thought this site cangive me the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having thoughts is natural but don’t act upon those thoughts by committing haram sexual acts or don’t waste time indulging in those sexual thoughts rather you should focus on something else and distract yourself. It is typically thoughts such as these that may lead you to committing bad things so I suggest spending time maybe reading the Quran, avoiding people you maybe fantasise about, spending time in good company or doing something you enjoy as a hobby.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it haram to get crazy by thinking about sex?

Yes it is, since hedonism is against the spirit of Islam - as is lying for unethical ends; but note that sex itself, is not.

Comment: Hedonism is definitely against the spirit of Islam, but fantasising about sex usually does entail the philosophical baggage of hedonism right? I mean, it is quite the leap in logic to conclude that enjoying a sexual fantasy is a precursor to actively restructuring ones moral principles according to “pleasure” and nothing else

Comment: @UbaidHassan: I'm not making that leap in logic; I'm simply pointing out that hedonism is against the spirit of Islam.